# Преобразование типа Integer в Strint Android data binding

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-data-binding

Подскажите как заставить работать **@BindingConversion**, никак не могу найти ошибку.
Пишу приложение на Android и пытаюсь использовать для этого Binding и ViewModel.
Проблема следующая. Есть Фрагмент с расположенным на нем текстовым полем

```
            <data>
                <variable
                    name="modelDoc"
                    type="ru.viewModel.ViewModelDoc" />

            </data>
       ..............
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCountAll"
                android:text="@{String.valueOf(modelDoc.countAllBarDoc)}"/>
```

Сама переменная **countAllBarDoc** представляет из себя

```
          MutableLiveData<Integer> countAllBarDoc;
```

Никак не получается сделать вывод без использования конструкции **String.valueOf()**
Пытаюсь во фрагменте сделать функцию преобразования типов, но она, почему то, не работает

```
@BindingConversion
public static String convertIntegerToString(Integer countAllBarDoc) {
    return "Integer.toString(countAllBarDoc)";
}
```

Пробовал разные комбинации названий (convertIntToString, convertintToString и тп), но он в нее даже и не заходит.

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает `String.valueOf()`? Это самое лаконичное решение. Плюс `@BindingConversion` метод будет применяться ко всем совпадающим по типам значениям, задаваемым через биндинг, что может вам аукнуться в другом месте. Если не нравиться конвертация в разметке - как вариант, можно заменить `MutableLiveData<Integer>` на `MutableLiveData<String>` и конвертировать число в строку на уровне источника данных. Так же можете почитать про `@BindingAdapter` и `@BindingMethods`

Comment: Возможно вы и правы, но я хочу научиться пользоваться @BindingConversion. Про все другие методы, что вы описали я тоже знаю. И про то что будет применяться ко всему подряд я тоже понимаю. Но не понимаю почему у меня вообще не хочет срабатывать

Comment: Старайтесь задавать вопросы точнее. Так и пишите что хотите разобраться как работает именно эта опция и как её использовать. Сейчас формулировка вопроса приводит к выводу, что вы хотите любым способом избавиться от `String.valueOf()` в разметке.

Comment: Поправил пост. А по существу вопроса, есть ещё предложения?

Comment: Помогите хоть кто нибудь... (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аннотация `@BindingConversion` регистрирует метод как конвертер типов.
Имя метода не имеет значения, важны только тип параметра и возвращаемый тип - они должны совпадать с типом данных и ожидаемым типом соответственно.
В теории ваш метод верный, но проблема конкретно этого примера в том, что атрибут `android:text` применяется вызовом метода `TextView.setText()`, который имеет несколько перегрузок. Одна из них `setText(int resId)` принимает id string-ресурса и она как раз подходит по типу к вашему значению - поэтому конвертация не применяется.
В итоге число интерпретируется как id ресурса, которого не существует.
Если вы замените тип `Integer` у `LiveData` и метода-конвертера на любой другой, например `Long` - всё будет работать как ожидается.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, так все стало гораздо понятнее.